# Should ViewBinding properties in fragments always have a backing non-nullable property?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-viewbinding

I've been reading https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding and was thinking about how they define their view binding property in a fragment.

This is the sample code:

```
private var _binding: ResultProfileBinding? = null
// This property is only valid between onCreateView and
// onDestroyView.
private val binding get() = _binding!!

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    _binding = ResultProfileBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    val view = binding.root
    return view
}

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    _binding = null
}
```

So `_binding` is a nullable because the reference to the view will be destroyed in `onDestroyView()`. However, they use `binding` as a backing property, which retrieves `_binding` and makes it non-nullable (whatever the equivalent to force unwrapping is called in Kotlin).

The question is why should we have `_binding` and `binding` and which one should be used? It feels like if you are trying to make `_binding` nullable, then why make it essentially non-nullable with `binding` and risk accessing the view when it's destroyed?

Comment: "they use binding as a backing property" The other way around; `binding_` is the backing property for `binding`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`_binding` is `nullable` so that it can be set to null in `onDestroyView`, avoiding any [memory leaks](https://lordraydenmk.github.io/2020/view-binding/). but if you tried to access views using `_binding` then you will have to write `_binding!!.someView` every time you access any view, use of non-null assertion(`!!`) quickly becomes redundant and verbose.

So to remove this redundancy there is non-nullable `binding`. Now you can access your views as `binding.someView`, no need to use non-null assertion (!!). This can not cause any issue, since views should only be accessed between `onCreateView` and `onDestroyView`.

Answer (score 4):

The reason behind this is to make code easier to read and maintain when **you know for sure** that you won't try to access the view before `onCreateView` and after `onDestroyView`. The non-null property avoids the unnecessary `?` or `!!` null safety operators every time you're trying to reach the binding.

On the other hand if you're uncertain about your call sequences and **may** try to access the fragment view when the view is destroyed, you wouldn't need to take that extra step and put your binding instance in a backing property. The null safety is your dearest friend in this case.